# Can I get the CSS3 border-image to work on all modern browsers (IE 9+, Chrome and Firefox)?

Tags: html, border, css3pie, css

I want to use border-image for a fluid scaling CSS container. Is it possible to enable this CSS3 functionality on all modern browsers using some .js framework? If not, is there a good substitute?

For an example of what I want to achieve see: 
http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

Comment: `-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;` - Safari 5 -
`-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;` - Opera -
`border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;` - Normal -

Just some examples

Comment: Well, it doesn't work in browsers other than Safari and Firefox 3.1 (Alpha). I'm searching for a solution to enable this on all browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border-image property is not supported by IE, check: http://caniuse.com/border-image for browser support.

But, css3pie can make it possible for you to use a border-image in IE 6-9:
http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

Comment: +1. I've been using CSS3Pie for ages (and I'm a big fan of it) but I didn't realise they'd added `border-image` to it. That's a big help.

Comment: However, I would say this: be careful of suggesting w3schools.com as a resource; it's got a really bad reputation around here. For browser support info, I recommend visiting http://CanIUse.com instead.

Comment: I haven't looked into CSS3Pie but it seems worth the try. I will create a test project and test it in different browsers. If it works, I will update your answer! I, I, I ...

Comment: @Spudley, thanks for the advice. I've changed it to caniuse.com

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you can't.

`border-image` is not supported in IE9 or IE10. It is available in IE11, though.

Most other browsers do support it, but there are significant gaps -- notably the Android browswer, which doesn't support it in any version.

Most of the shiny new browser features that have been introduced in recent years can be back-ported into older browsers using a Javascript polyfill library. This has helped make it easier to start using a lot of these features, as developers could use the new feature without compromising their site too much for users of older browsers.

<strike>Unfortunately, `border-image` doesn't have any polyfills, so if you use it, you will just have to accept that users of IE<=10 and android users will not see your border image. Sorry.</strike>

Correction: It seems as if CSS3Pie has added polyfill support for `border-image`. That's really nice; I've always been a fan of CSS3Pie, but I wasn't aware that they'd added this feature. It does look as if it's not 100% feature-complete, but it's really nice to have.

You'll still have a problem with Android users, and a few other older browsers, but with CSS3Pie supporting it, the biggest barrier to using it has been removed. Nice one.

Refer to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image) to see a browser compatibility chart for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.This should serve the need for IE browsers:)

```css
.borderImg{
background-image:linear-gradient(to left, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(221, 221, 221), rgb(221, 221, 221), rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
 background-repeat : no-repeat;
 background-size :600px 3px;
 background-position:bottom; 
  padding-bottom:8px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="borderImg">
  Applying border
</div>
```